# Invalid syntax when importing openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, unix, redhat, openpyxl

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 26 2019, 13:23:47)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openpyxl

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 396
    return f"{get_column_letter(min_col)}{min_row}:{get_column_letter(max_col)}{max_row}"
```

Is there any additional packages needs to be installed?

Can anyone let me know the reason behind this behavior, since it is working fine on windows and macos.

Comment: You have installed openpyxl incorrectly.

Comment: @CharlieClark how is it installed incorrectly? what is the recommended method.

Comment: An up to date version of pip will install < version 3.

Comment: @CharlieClark updating the pip version to 20.1 fixed the issue. There was some misconfiguration in the system which restricted the update to 19.0.

Answer (score 5):

The openpyxl package you've installed uses [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). They appeared in Python 3.6. You should switch from Python 2.7.5 to Python 3.6 or later. Or find an openpyxl package version that's compatible with Python 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will try with downgraded version of openpyxl that supports python2.7